# Android app showing up in Google Play search only on certain devices

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest, device

I have tested my app on 2.2, 2.3 and 4.0. It works as designed on all versions. When I search Google Play Store from my Samsung Phone, both the Free and Paid versions show up in the list. When I search from my Tablet (Double Power T708) neither app shows up. Apps do show up so I know it is not the connection. I have looked at the device compatibility list and the T708 is not listed, but then how are the other apps showing up???

Below is my AndroidManifest.xml. 
I am hoping someone can help me shed some light on this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.SocialWriter"
    android:installLocation="auto"
    android:versionCode="10"
    android:versionName="1.1" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" 
              android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <supports-screens 
                  android:smallScreens="true"
                  android:normalScreens="true"
                  android:largeScreens="true" 
                  android:xlargeScreens="true" 
                  android:anyDensity="true"  />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />



    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <activity
            android:name=".SocialWriterActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>           
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".RegisterActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" > 
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".NewBookActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >             
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".AboutAuthorActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" > 
        </activity>        
        <activity
            android:name=".SearchCirclesActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" > 
        </activity>     
        <activity
            android:name=".SearchPublicActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" > 
        </activity>                     
        <activity
            android:name=".SearchRequestActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" > 
        </activity>         
        <activity
            android:name=".SearchPublishedActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" > 
        </activity>          
        <activity
            android:name=".EditBookActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" > 
        </activity>             
        <activity
            android:name=".ViewBookActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" > 
        </activity>           
        <activity
            android:name=".EditParagraphActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" > 
        </activity>           
        <activity
            android:name=".BookForumActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" > 
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".EditBookInfoActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" > 
        </activity>           
        <activity
            android:name=".ViewPagesActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" > 
        </activity>           
        <activity
            android:name=".RequestCenterActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" > 
        </activity>           
        <activity
            android:name=".AuthorBioActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" > 
        </activity>              
        <activity
            android:name=".EditAccountActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" > 
        </activity>              
        <activity
            android:name=".ReadBookActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" > 
        </activity>          
        <activity
            android:name=".TermsActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" > 
        </activity> 
        <activity
            android:name=".MyIntents"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" > 
        </activity>                
        <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
                      android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

How long ago did you publish the app?
Google play takes awhile to update the devices that can use your app.
I know that when I first uploaded my app, google play said that there were a wopping total of 0 devices capable of using the app.

Comment: App was published several weeks before I posted this message. It is still not showing up on the tablet.